# Google is not defined except it is

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use a module for prestashop that throw a googlemap.
I want to change the position of the view dinamicaly, so I did a test like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    function moveToLocation(lat, lng){
    console.log(google);
        var center = google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        // using global variable:
        map.panTo(center);
    }
    moveToLocation(48, 12);
});
```

The console give me an error `Google is not defined` so I checked my console and I found that

[image: console return for 'window']

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

**Edit** My script is loaded before this :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBCOuQvJWQQxSde3s5RNCBZmB1VkfFKXxw&amp;callback=AdvancedStoreMapsInitMap&amp;language=fr" async="" defer=""></script>
```

Comment: what steps have you tried to solve this issue? is the Google Script being loaded well?

Comment: DOM is loaded doesn't mean the Google API is loaded. How do you load it and where? Your code is incomplete.

Comment: @MrUpsidown The API is loaded by an addon, it is obfuscated so I don't really know what he's doing.

Comment: How it works essentially and how Google instructs you to use their API is to load the script with `async defer` and provide a callback function (first page of the docs). All your map code should be within that callback function or called from within that function, which ensures the API is fully loaded before you try to access it.

Comment: Yes, and that's what is used in your edit: `AdvancedStoreMapsInitMap` is the callback function. So either you have access to it, or... not.

Comment: Ok so I can't do anything beside contacting the devs of the addon and ask them an access to the callback. Tank you very much for your answer @MrUpsidown

Comment: @MrUpsidown You actually should answer that so I validate because it is very important to know this behavior of the google api (I didn't noticed it in the doc, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it works essentially and how Google instructs you to use their API is to load the script with `async defer` and provide a callback function as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

All your map code should be within that callback function or called from within that function, which ensures the API is fully loaded before you try to access it.

The add-on you are using is loading the map and provides `AdvancedStoreMapsInitMap` as the callback function. If you don't have access to that part of the code, then you have a problem.

You could wait some time before executing your code, which *should* ensure that the API script has loaded. I said "should" because you cannot be sure it is loaded even if you wait 2 seconds or even more... (network issues, etc.)

Or you could check directly like that:

```
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') { ... }
```

You could check that multiple times with a timeout for example. And when it is, execute your code. A bit of a hack but that should work.

Also note that you can't include the API script multiple times on the same page. It will generate an error: *You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.*

Comment: Ok, this is very clear, I will use an onclick event (since it was what I wanted from the begining) until the dev give me access to the callback :) Thank you

Comment: Welcome. Even in your click event, you should make the checks as provided above...

Comment: Yes. I will. Now it tells me that `map is undefined` :D but I'm moving forward thanks to you ^^

Comment: But I saw in another question that map is only accessible through the api scope so I have to define it again in my function :(

Comment: If the variable was declared within the API callback function then you won't be able to access it... If it was defined in the global scope, you should have access to it. Another reason to maybe come up with your own add-on, if the one you are using doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the code inside a document load event instead of DOMContentLoaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function moveToLocation(lat, lng){
    console.log(google);
        var center = google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        // using global variable:
        map.panTo(center);
    }
    moveToLocation(48, 12);
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the same. DOM might be ready and the API has not finished loading.